# Cant see full content when wallpost using facebook sdk

Tags: android, android-facebook

Iam using following method to make a wall post using facebook sdk 3+ . After posting the story, I noticed that there is no complete content posted.About Half of it is missing.
Is there any workaround for this, or do I have to go for another method?

```
public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Title");
    params.putString("description", fbText);// The contents here are missing.


    facebook.dialog(this, "feed",params, new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: How many characters does "fbText" contain?

Comment: @JoaoBiriba: Its more than 300...

Answer (score 0):

I see it's a common problem among Facebook SDKs

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761737/description-is-trunctuated-when-i-post-desctription-from-ios-using-facebook-sdk

Someone try to workaround this issue putting the text in the caption value instead of description